# numeric solutions on quadric surfaces

Tags: quadratic-forms

Maybe it's a trivial thing, but I can't seem to find solution I'm looking for. I need to find a parametric solution to the following equation ($\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite):

$$
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}+c=0
$$

How to find $x$, then, in some parametric form? That is, I want to generate some $n-1$ dimensional parameter (something like spherical coördinates) and get one of the solutions in the original space.

Comment: I don't understand what "not a nice ellipsoid" means. Did you want to say it's not an ellipsoid at all? I do not know how ellipsoids are divided into nice and naughty... You do need an affine transformation to center and align the equation, after that, (hyperbolic) trigonometric functions give a parametrization as in [section 3.4 here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~sterk/Bouwkunde/hoofdstuk3.pdf).

Comment: Naughty ellipsoids arise naturally when you realize you don't know how to solve a simple quadratic equation in the middle of your master thesis :) Thanks for reminding about affine transformations, actually, and the nice lengthy reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can factor the problem by completing the square as follows,
\begin{align}
x^T A x + b^T x + c &= (x^T A x + b^T x + \frac{b^TA^{-1}b}{4}) + c - \frac{b^TA^{-1}b}{4} \\
&= (x^T A^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2}b^T A^{-1/2})(A^{1/2} x + \frac{1}{2}A^{-1/2} b) + c - \frac{b^TA^{-1}b}{4} \\
&= (x + \frac{1}{2}A^{-1} b)^T A (x + \frac{1}{2}A^{-1} b) + c - \frac{b^TA^{-1}b}{4},
\end{align}

or
$$x^T A x + b^T x + c = (x-p)^T A (x-p) - q$$
where $p := -\frac{1}{2}A^{-1} b$ and $q := \frac{b^TA^{-1}b}{4} - c$. So, an equivalent formulation of your equation is,
$$(x-p)^T A (x-p) = q.$$

So, the solution set is an ellipsoid centered at $p$ with axes given by the singular vectors $u_i$ of $A$ and axis lengths $\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sigma_i}$.

**Edit:** from the comment below for completeness, a numerical scheme for drawing samples from the solution set is,

1. Draw a collection of gaussian random vectors and put them as the columns of the matrix $X$.
2. Normalize the columns of $X$ to have length $\sqrt{q}$.
3. Compute a collection of random points on the ellipse as $S = A^{-1/2} X + p \mathbb{1}^T$ ($\mathbb{1}^T$ is the vector of all ones).

Comment: Right to the point, thanks! Dammit, I was trying to solve it the same way, but in reverse order yesterday, but apparently not for long enough.

Comment: Hey, isn't it $\frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sigma_i}$ on the last line?

Comment: Also, to complete the answer, could you also add the way of generating solutions numerically? E.g.:
1) generate a bunch of random vectors $X$ with each column a random vector
2) normalize each column of X to $\sqrt{q}$ (random points on a sphere or radius $\sqrt{q}$)
3) points on ellipse (random solutions) are $S = A^{-\frac{1}{2}}X + pe^T$

Comment: Ok, edited the answer to include your comments.